# How does my questionnaire analysis plan sound?

Tags: spss, survey, likert, group-differences

I will soon have the results of a questionnaire that I have carried out, and I have made a plan on how I will analyse the data. I was hoping that someone could comment on my plan to advise me.

About the questionnaire: there are 3 groups of people (let's call them `A`, `B`, and `C`), and they have all answered a questionnaire with 18 questions, all on a 5-point Likert scale. The questions are grouped into 4 subsets. Group `A` is the reference group, and my aim is to see if the the responses of group `B` or `C` are different to `A`.

The primary outcome measure is the percentage of the total possible score for each subset of questions.
The secondary outcome measure is the percentage of the total possible score for each question.

The current outline in which I would present the data is as follows:

- Descriptive analysis: I would detail the demographics of each group of patients and use ANOVA or Kruskal–Wallis (most likely as the data will probably not be normally distributed) to determine if there are differences in the demographics of the groups
- Primary outcome measure: Use ANOVA or Kruskal–Wallis
- Secondary outcome measure: Use ANOVA or Kruskal–Wallis

As I understand with ANOVA and Kruskal–Wallis, you can find out where a difference lies if the statistic comes out below the threshold. This is something I would plan on doing.

My problem is that I am unsure how I could go about testing to see if any of the demographic variables are associated with outcome. Regression?
Furthermore if a demographic variable is associated with outcome, how can I adjust for that in my statistical analysis?
I will be using SPSS.

Comment: In my opinion questions on possible interactions of various demographic variables to the outcome should have been stated in your research plan before sampling. After collecting the data, it is possible to have a significant interaction of the outcome with some of them only due to the sampling error.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You make a good point about sampling error and one of the groups will only contain a small amount of people in it and so this is even more likely in this group. My main aim is not to test if demographic variables affect outcome but it is something I would like to test to see if it is something I should adjust for in my analysis.

Comment: I thing that the only valid way to see if an effect that appear between group and outcome is due to a demographic variable is to put this variable in the ANOVA model. Thus, a simple (although not methodologically right) approach is to run Analyze > General Linear Model > Univariate, put the outcome in the cell Dependent Variable, put Group variable in the Fixed Factor(s) cell and all demographic variables you believe that interact with the outcome in Fixed Factor(s), Random Factor(s) and Covariate(s) cells according to their properties. Of course you should be careful for the data assumptions!